# How do I take the derivative of y as well as x?

Tags: derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(y^3-4x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}2}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
Note that $\text{RHS}$ (Right Hand Side) is $0$, since $2$ is constant.
By the linearity of the differential operator, we can write
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}(y^3-4x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y^3}{\mathrm{d}x} -4 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}2}{\mathrm{d}x}$$
By the chain rule, we can write
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y^3}{\mathrm{d}y} \times \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} -4 \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$$
So $$3y^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-4=0$$
 So we have $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{4}{3y^2} \quad \left( \text{given that} y \neq 0 \right)$$

WRT $x$.

Comment: OK! But..what is the question?

Comment: That looks Ok to me, what was the question again?

Comment: The equation is a differential equation, saying there should be some specific relation between $y$ and some of her derivatives. In this case only the first derivative.

Comment: It seems that given $y^3-4x=2$ you want us to check if $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4}{3y^2}$$ is correct or not? Well, its correct.